# Parse data and present PNG image

Tags: python, file, computer-vision, yuv

I have a file (rawbytes.data). It contains raw bytes as YUV NV12 format. It contains one frame of a grayscale image(640x480). How would i parse this data file and present a png?

The .data file looks as follows in Sublime Text:

0000 0000 0000 0000 6c05 0000 8002 0000
e001 0000 0707 0807 0808 0a0b 0e0f 1112
1515 1512 120f 0f0d 0c0e 0e10 1011 1110
0f0d 0e0b 0b0c 0e0e 0f0d 0c0e 0c0c 0b0a
0908 0a0a 0a0a 0908 0a08 0808 0708 0809
0809 0b09 0b09 0b0f 1214 1416 1413 1112
0f09 0809 0c0e 1010 1111 1110 0e0e 0d0c
0a08 0807 0708 0708 0707 0708 0606 0707
0707 0807 0708 0708 0807 0707 0708 0807
0808 0707 0707 0807 0808 0706 0707 0807
0807 0807 0707 0807 0707 0808 0808 0708
0706 0707 0807 0708 0808 0808 0808 0708
0808 0807 0808 0708 0807 0809 0707 0908
0808 0808 0908 0708 0707 0807 0808 0708
0707 0808 0708 0809 0808 0708 0708 0707
0808 0808 0707 0707 0708 0807 0809 0708
0808 0809 0908 0807 0809 0908 0808 0808
0808 0808 0809 0808 0809 0808 0808 0808
0908 0808 0908 0908 0909 0809 0908 0808
0708 0809 0909 0909 0809 0908 0908 0809
0909 0809 0909 0808 0808 0809 0808 0909
0808 0709 0808 0808 0809 0809 0809 0808

I tried to use python to open file in 'rb' mode and write it in 'wb' to a png file but doesn't work.

```
    with open('rawbytes.data', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    with open('picture_out.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://gist.github.com/fzakaria/2472889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting raw data to png using the following:

```
rawData = open("foo.raw" 'rb').read()
imgSize = (h,w)
img = Image.fromstring('L', imgSize, rawData, 'raw', 'F;16')
img.save("foo.png")
```

where h and w will be height and width

Comment: I made a few changes. Intead of fromstring i used frombytes. Also, when I don't have the size of the file like I have in this case, how to go about that ? I tried using imgsize = rawData.size but that doesn't work.